# Need solution regarding generic c# method

Tags: c#

I am trying to make my method generic and I am stuck at a point and need your assistance. The code scenario is I have an abstract class say `MyBaseAbs` which contains common properties:

```
public abstract class MyBaseAbs
{
    public string CommonProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp2 { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have child classes:

```
public class Mychild1: MyBaseAbs
{
    public string Mychild1Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Mychild1Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Mychild1Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

and another child class:

```
public class Mychild2: MyBaseAbs
{
    public string Mychild1Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Mychild2Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to create a common method which needs to perform some operations on the basis of `Mychild1` and `Mychild2`, so what I did is:

```
public MyCustomClass SaveOperation<T>(T myObj)
        where T : MyBaseAbs
{
    SaveObject obj = new SaveObject();

}
```

so inside this method I need to write common code which does the mapping for `SaveObject` object according to the child object passed. How can I determine which object is passed and use properties accordingly.

Comment: there is not enough information about SaveOperation method. how ever one obvious solution is to check for type. `if(myObj is Mychild1)`

Comment: If your code needs to do different things for different child classes, why make it generic? Write a `SaveOperation` for each concrete child class and (if necessary) have a private `SaveOperation` based on the base class that has the common code and each concrete method can call.

Comment: What class is `SaveOperation` in?

Comment: hi 
i know that is the obvious solution, if i got to determine the objects using "is" then i would preferred more another method which would have been receiving objects accordingly, i am looking for more generic solution.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to create a base `Save` function in your base class and make it virtual.

Then override the method in your child classes. This way when you call the `Save` method in your `SaveOperation` it should call the appropriate method from the correct child class.

```
public abstract class MyBaseAbs
{
    public string CommonProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp2 { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp3 { get; set; }

    public virtual void Save() { }
}

public class Mychild1: MyBaseAbs
{
    public string Mychild1Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Mychild1Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Mychild1Prop3 { get; set; }

    public override void Save() { 
        //Implementation for Mychild1
    }
}

public class Mychild2: MyBaseAbs
{
    public string Mychild1Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Mychild2Prop2 { get; set; }

    public override void Save() { 
        //Implementation for Mychild2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bojan for the response but i can create methods inside business object.

Comment: @SanjayBathre I'm sorry I don't quite understand your comment. What are business objects in your case?

Comment: the classes that i have mentioned are those.

Comment: I see. So in your first comment you wanted to say you "can't create methods" - that threw me a bit off :). May I ask why not? And if it is so than you might consider the answer from @user449689

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify your business objects, you can check the type of the concrete class in the `SaveOperation` method:

```
public MyCustomClass SaveOperation<T>(T myObj)
        where T : MyBaseAbs
{
    SaveObject obj = new SaveObject();

    if (myObj is Mychild1) {
        Mychild1 mychild1 = (Mychild1) myObj;

        // Business logic for object of type Mychild1

    } else if (myObje is Mychild2) {
        Mychild2 mychild2 = (Mychild2) myObj;

        // Business logic for object of type Mychild2

    }

}
```

Notice that this is not a very solid solution as, if you are creating new objects that implement your abstract class, you will have to remeber to add another branch in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

As @BojanB mentioned, the obvious solution would be to create a virtual method in your base class and override it in the derived, but if you cannot modify the code there then you can create a method for each derived class and create a dictionary that maps each type to its method:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Action<MyBaseAbs, MyCustomClass>> _saveOperations = 
                            new Dictionary<Type, Action<MyBaseAbs, MyCustomClass>>();

//You can then set an entry for each of your derived classes
_saveOperations[typeof(Mychild1)] = (myObj, myCustomObj) =>
{
    //Mychild1-specific logic
};

public MyCustomClass SaveOperation(MyBaseAbs obj)
{
    //do the common saving operations here 
    var result = new MyCustomClass();
    //....

    var actualType = obj.GetType();
    if(_saveOperations.ContainsKey(actualType))
    {
        _saveOperations[actualType](obj, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can then add an item to the dictionary for each derived class. It is the same concept as using the `is` operator but allows you to add methods for more derived types without modifying the original `SaveOperation` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use C#'s As-Operator as follows:

```
Mychild1 child1 = myObj as Mychild1;
if(child1 != null) {
   //Here you can use child1.Mychild1Prop1 forexample
}
```

Link to msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx